# Is there a way to detect a face image is frontal or profile?

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection, face-recognition

I was wondering if there is a way to determine if a face image is frontal face or profile,it is just a 2D image.

Comment: I did a computer vision project once to determine the angle. We used a lot of training images to build a model. It was closely coupled to face detection. The preciser the face detection was, the more the number of correct angles it computed.

Comment: You can use a haar cascade with both a front and profile detector. OpenCV has a python/c++ implementation.

Comment: You might try the Android mobile vision API to do face detection.  This can detect both frontal and profile faces (when run in "accurate" mode), and will report head angles.  See here: https://developers.google.com/vision/face-detection-concepts